# How to get SilverStripe Watermarkable extension work properly after update with different locales

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have updated Silverstripe from **3.1.2** to **3.1.13** (framework, CMS and extensions). There are `silverstripe-watermarkable` and `silverstripe-translatable` extensions installed and working properly.
Now I have my watermark Image uploaded in `Settings > Watermark Image` on default locale (`lv_LV`).
Everything is okay, while I'm browsing website on default locale, but when I change to different available locale (let's say English or Russian) it throws me an error

> [Notice] getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error!

It's only one of several errors. The thing I have figured out up so far is that when I change `$watermark_path = $watermarkFile->getFullPath();` in  `silverstripe-watermarkable/code/ImageWatermarkExtension.php` to `my/path/to/actual/watermark_image.png`
it works well, so, what should I do to create solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution! I have been editing extension files, this is a bad manner. I have come up to changing only that `DataObject` which should be changed:

```
// mysite/code/MyImage.php
<?php

class MyImage extends WatermarkImage {
  ...
  public function getWatermark() {
    // in this example we assume has an image named "Watermark"
    $siteConfig = SiteConfig::current_site_config();
    if ($siteConfig->Watermark()) {
      return $siteConfig->getTranslation('lv_LV')->Watermark();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The issue were in `return $siteConfig->Watermark();` the key was `->getTranslation('lv_LV')`.
I've came up with

- Not changing extension `code` directory files
- Updating only `DataObject`, not the extension core

Comment: Now it works well (displaying watermark image on all images that extend MyImage DataObject class.